# Laravel 4.1 - queue:listen performance

Tags: performance, laravel, redis, queue, rabbitmq

I am trying to use the Queue system in Laravel (4.1). Everything works as expected, with both Redis (with the native driver) and RabbitMQ. 
The only "issue" I am experiencing is the poor performance. It looks like only 4 jobs per seconds can be processed (I push 1000 jobs in the queue to test it). Have you got any tip to improve the performance?

Comment: Hi Simone, where is Redis hosted? Redis can process thousands of reads or writes per second. Do you use [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining)?

Comment: I may be wrong here but I think this is the general functionality - the queue is checked on a regular basis with `queue:listen` and a bunch of jobs are fired off at the same time. But I doubt if the queue has 100 items, you get PHP doing 100 things at once, after all it's just a single PHP process checking the queue. You could probably make multiple queue listeners to handle more throughput, though.

Comment: @alexrussell: yes, I thought that too. The problem with multiple queue listeners is CPU usage, though. I think I will choose a different approach and "pack" more jobs into one so that whenever the queue worker is called, it processes more stuff at once. Thank you!

Comment: @TwBert: I might try your approach as well and see what happens with Laravel, thank you.

Comment: @SimoneFolador - can you please report back with solution or your experiences with this issue?

Comment: Hi, in the end I chose another approach without queues. I guess that the daemon-queue-worker present in the new version of Laravel (4.2) targets this issue: http://laravel.com/docs/queues#daemon-queue-worker. I still haven't tried it so I can't say how better it is compared to the "old" version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a old question but I thought I would post anyway.  The problem is Laravel's default listener is not really a true queue consumer, it polls the queue at regular intervals unless it is already busy with a job.  Using a true AMQP requires some additional libraries to be install from pecl. You  can find that plugin [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp). I would also suggest using this composer package for you [PHP AMQP library](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib). You would then need to write your Laravel command.

Currently I'm writing a RabbitMQ handler for Laravel that will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Please keep me posted on your work.It may become handy in the future projects.

Comment: > "Currently I'm writing a RabbitMQ handler for Laravel that will resolve this issue." OK, did you wrote it?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for anyone coming here, the queue:work command has a daemon mode that runs just like queue:listen except that it doesn't have to restart/reload Laravel each time, making it much more performant. See the docs:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues